# Implement a logical part as Generic one in AngularsJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have recently started working on ANGULARJS in which I was encountered a case where I need some guidance to go through. Am implementing a message section in my application(**ASP NET MVC - ANGULARJS**).Currently I have implemented the message section for a specific module under a particular **ng-app** and under particular **ng-controller**. Now I need the same functionality to be used inside another module. It's like duplicating the same code again that ng-app under that ng-controller which was not a good approach. I just wanted like and plug and play kind of approach for my **ANGULARJ**S code.

I have used **2 service,1 directive** under that particular ng-app and some functions inside a particular controller. All I want is to make these one a common code and to be used inside under any ng-app and ng-controller.

Is this possible? If so how can I achieve.

Let me know if the query was unclear

Comment: Can you post some sample code here ? What is the message section you are talking about. Is this kind of notification messages based on user actions ?

Answer (score 0):

You said you used 2 service, 1 directive, and controller etc for your messaging feature. If you want to re-use it across various applications, you need to bundle all of this as a module. for example:

```js
angular.module('customMessaging', [])
  .controller('messagingCtrl', function(messenger, messageManager) {
    ....
  })
  .directive('messagingDir', function() {
    return {
      controller: 'messagingCtrl'
        ...
    }
  })
  .service('messenger', function() {
    ...
  })
  .service('messageManager', function() {
    ...
  })
```

Now you can specify this as a dependency of any of your angular applications as shown below to access the directive, services and controller anywhere in the app:

```
angular.module('myfirstApp', ['customMessaging']);
angular.module('mySecondApp', ['customMessaging']);
```

Comment: Is CustomMessaging should be an ng-app for Message View?

Comment: @SelvamM I don't know what you mean by *Message View*. Maybe it's the directive? Whatever *view* template you need to reuse should be a directive. Once you add `CustomMessaging` as a dependent module you get access to everything in it in your application. The application should only have one `ng-app`

Comment: Can we inject $scope and have $scope.fn={} in custommessaging and can be called from injected module of custommessaging?

Comment: @SelvamM When you add  custommessaging as dependency on myfirstApp, all the controllers, directives, and services etc registered in it become injectable in your main application module which is myfirstApp.  These controllers, directives etc has their own scope. When you create another app you can include custommessaging in it as well. If you don't understand what I'm saying you probably need to read and learn more about AngularJS. sorry I don't know how to explain it any better. Maybe look at some open source angular projects in github and see how reusable libraries are created

Comment: I have defined separate module for message say chat with all directives,service,controller with scope functions inside.
var chatApp = angular.module('Chat', []);
chatApp.Service - service registered.
chatApp.controller - controller instantiated with scope functions.

I have invoked chat module from main app where I need this chat section say

angular.module(main, ['Chat']);

But the scope functions inside chat was not getting called. Am followed the approach what you have told.

Comment: @SelvamM So what's the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112873/discussion-between-selvam-m-and-t-j).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I have moved the message related functions such as services, directive and controller related functions into separate JavaScript file . And invoked this JavaScript file where I need message related functionalities.

Let us say that JS as Message.JS . In Message.JS I have used the app variable(Instantiated app from the JS Specific to the page globally).

**JS specific to that page**

```
var app = angular.module('appname',[]);  
app.controller(...)
```

**Message.JS**

I have used the same app in my message.JS since message controller falls under that app.

```
app.service(...)

app.controller('messagecontroller',[]...)
```

When ever I need to invoke a function inside MessageController I will use Broadcast in angular to achieve this.For more info http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html

Regards,
**Selvam.M**